# Where can I find the changelog for Play 2.0.4

Tags: documentation, playframework, playframework-2.0

Where can I find the changelog for Play 2.0.4 and generally for any other releases of Play framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All announcements for new Play's releases are always available at [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/e16pHojeSvs) first. Typically they contains summary of changes.

> ### highlights:
>
> - introduce ExternalAssets controller (useful in dev mode when one needs to deal with lots of assets)
> - switch date handling in Assets controller to Joda Time
> - switch time zone in Assets controller from UTC to GMT
> - make date parsing in Assets controller more resilient
> - Global.onStop is now invoked properly in prod mode

You can also check [LightHouse's tickets for the 2.0.4 milestone](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/milestones/155624-204) for more details.

Tip: to find tickets for specific release click the `Milestones` button on the top nav (but not the down arrow) it will allow you to switch to the list of the `Completed Milestones`

Comment: thank you couldn't find the 2.0.4 milestone.

Comment: Ach cause it's tricky, I'm confused about that every time :) check the tip I added to the answer.

Comment: right.. thanks! btw nice rep number (ATM)

Comment: Actually, if someone from the Play team is listening: it would be nice if the changelogs would also be linked from playframework.org since many people have problems finding it.